# SQL Can I use CASE statement with addition condition in a JOIN condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use join with case statement and addition condition, for example :

```
SELECT
    TableA.* 
FROM
    TableA A
INNER JOIN 
    TableB B ON A.ID =  B.TableA_ID 
    CASE
        WHEN @zerocond = 1 
            THEN AND A.OrganizationId != '0'
        WHEN @zerocond = 2
            THEN AND COM.OrganizationId IN(1,2)
    END
```

But this code results in a syntax error. Can anyone help to explain a little?

Comment: `CASE` is an **expression**, not a statement. It returns a scalar value. However, don't use a `CASE` expression in your `ON` or `WHERE` either; it is not SARGable. Use proper `AND` and `OR` boolean logic.

Comment: @larnu CASE is an operator that use an expression....

Comment: `CASE` is an expression, @SQLpro . I'm not sure what your comment is saying I'm afraid.

Comment: @larnu BETWEEN, IN, LIKE, CASE, UNION, INTERSECT, EXCEPT, JOIN are called operators in SQL. Nothing to do with "expression"...

Comment: No, @SQLpro , it's an expression. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): *"The CASE **expression** has two formats"* It also continues to reference it as an expression the entire way through.

Comment: @larnu CASE expression refer to the complete writing of the operator CASE, with its multiple parts. Not to the operator itself. This is algebrae ! In ISO/IEC SQL standard part 2 : Foundation, the syntax speaks about "operand"... which are relative to ... operators !

Comment: @SQLpro if you feel the documentation is wrong, I suggest you submit a PR. That's the best way to submit corrections. If you are correct, then it will be accepted.

Comment: @larnu I have stop my MVP program since 2 years because I am in retirement.... It is not to restart it for some light trouble in the doc.... I prefer suggesting modification about very bad translation of the official MS doc into french.... !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Case When then` in `Join` Condition and in `Where` Clause is not possible in this case
What you are trying to achieve is doable with `And` and `OR` like below.

```
SELECT
    TableA.* 
FROM
    TableA A
INNER JOIN 
    TableB B ON A.ID =  B.TableA_ID 
    
Where ((@zerocond = 1 
            AND A.OrganizationId != '0')
        OR (@zerocond = 2
             AND COM.OrganizationId IN(1,2)))
```

Comment: *"Using Case When then in Join Condition and in Where Clause is not possible."* This statement is false. You *can* [use a `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` or `ON`] it's just ill-advised.

Comment: what do you think now?

Comment: This solution solved my problem.
Thanks @magnus